# Create variables and require packages in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, ejs

Is it possible to run custom JavaScript in EJS templates?

I'm looking for the equivalent of the following Jade code:

```
- var Fs = require("fs")
- var foo = 42;
| #{foo}
```

This will create the `Fs` and `foo` variables and display `42`.

Does EJS have this power?

From what I see, the following snippet does the same thing (without requiring the `fs` package):

```
<% var foo = 42; %>
<%= foo %>
```

Is this the right way or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is!

As you can see here http://www.embeddedjs.com/

In the example they are writing things from an array

```
<% for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {%>
    <li><%= link_to(supplies[i], 'supplies/'+supplies[i]) %></li>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Well, actually that's a list of items. I am referring here strictly to creating variables. I saw that if I pass the `require` function, that works fine. However, is it possible to have multiple JS lines to be evaluated, without wrapping each line with `<%` and `%>`?

Comment: Yes you can. If you test on their site you will see it work. However, to display something you will have to  use <%= %>

Comment: OK, add an example and I will review it.